# Need DataGridView Update

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

### I'm new at c# .Net and I'm working to develop c# winform application. I need your help.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{ 
    OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Burak YEŞİLYURT\Desktop\secret.accdb"); 
    OleDbCommand komutcu; 
    OleDbDataAdapter adpt; 
    DataSet ds; 
    public Form1() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        baglanti.Open(); 
        OleDbCommand komutcu = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM todo", baglanti); 
        OleDbDataAdapter adpt = new OleDbDataAdapter(komutcu); 
        DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
        adpt.Fill(ds); 
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; 

    } 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        OleDbCommandBuilder komut = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adpt); 
        DataSet yeni = new DataSet(); 
        yeni = ds.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified); //here i get the error
        adpt.Update(yeni.Tables[0]); 
    } 
}
```

---

When I debug my program, I get the following error at `yeni = ds.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);`

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "

My purpose: After filling `DataGridView` and user editing cell, save changes at cell.
I'm unable to solve this. Any help is welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: because ds is local to Form1 so the button click method can't access it   you need to instantiate ds as a public instance and then it will be accessible from both methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have define twice dataset oledbcommand and oldbDataAdapter so it could not work

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form 
    { 
        OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Burak YEŞİLYURT\Desktop\secret.accdb"); 
        OleDbCommand komutcu; 
        OleDbDataAdapter adpt; 
        DataSet ds; 
        public Form1() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
            baglanti.Open(); 
            komutcu = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM todo", baglanti); 
            adpt = new OleDbDataAdapter(komutcu); 
            ds = new DataSet(); 
            adpt.Fill(ds); 
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; 

        } 

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            OleDbCommandBuilder komut = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adpt); 
            DataSet yeni = new DataSet(); 
            yeni = ds.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified); //here i get the error
            adpt.Update(yeni.Tables[0]); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I think ıt doesnt need. coz ı dont  allow user to add row.

Comment: what you can do is to set a break point at this line and check ds value with espion

Comment: I cant see ds value coz Im new. İf you say where I can find Iwill be look up. :)

Comment: to add a breakpoint click on F9 when you set your cursor on line you will see a circle on your left and run in debug with F6 button

Comment: here an url to do it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Comment: no but now you can check if when you fill data you have data set a breakpoint in dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];  and check if there are data in datatable

Comment: there are too much stuffs i think i didnt find value whick what you want

Comment: but I just have checked my db. db has 6 row value

Comment: i find the mistake you have definied twice your ds replace DataSet ds = new DataSet();  by ds = new DataSet();

Comment: take code i edit please and set a breakpoint again in error line to check if ds is not null

Comment: @HassanBoutougha I said realized my adpt null but i dont understand 1 more thing. If my adpt is null, How adpt fill my ds and datagridview?

Comment: you have define twice command and adapter so it couldn't work ;-)

Comment: @HassanBoutougha you are my hero of day. Thanks for helping and paying attention.

Comment: thank you if i help thank to mark it (15 points is so good ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Fix you constructor

```
public Form1() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        baglanti.Open(); 
        OleDbCommand komutcu = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM todo", baglanti); 
        OleDbDataAdapter adpt = new OleDbDataAdapter(komutcu); 
        this.ds = new DataSet();  //there was an error in this line
        ..

    }
```

You created a local instance of `DataSet` in  a constructor, and you forgot to save  a reference to the class variable `ds`. Then in `button1_Click` you tried to access to uninitialized field `ds` (it had  a `null` value).

So, instead of this line

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

you should write

```
this.ds = new DataSet();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data     Source=C:\Users\Burak YEŞİLYURT\Desktop\secret.accdb"); 
    OleDbCommand komutcu; 
    OleDbDataAdapter adpt; 
    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
    public Form1() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        baglanti.Open(); 
        OleDbCommand komutcu = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM todo", baglanti); 
        OleDbDataAdapter adpt = new OleDbDataAdapter(komutcu); 
        //DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
        adpt.Fill(ds); 
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; 

    }
```

Comment: @AntonSizikov -  ha yes.  I was typing too fast.